# «Все сестрам по серьгам» – это всегда правильно?

Tags: семантика, литература, пословицы

Это известная пословица.   И вероятно,  она означает, что **и благодарность, и вину** надо всегда делить поровну?

А с чего бы это, и всегда ли?

Есть ли **в литературе или в жизни** примеры, когда эта пословица не считается правильной и используется как ирония  для оценки **несправедливого или просто не соответствующего** текущей ситуации действия?

Answer (score 1):

По знакомой мне практике употребления, это не столько пословица, сколько ироническая *присказка*, сопровождающая случившуюся (иногда - цинично планируемую) раздачу чего-либо (*каждому дали какую-то мелочь, чтобы никому не было обидно*). По одной из версий происхождения, это переведённая строка из белорусской **считалки** ( https://newslab.ru/article/182148 ):

> *Кожнай сястрыцы па завушніцы* (каждой сестре по серьге), *кожнаму сыну
> хатуль за спіну* (каждому сыну котомку за спину), *кожнаму брату па*
> *дукату*, *кожнаму старцу па стаўцу*
> (каждому старцу – по ставцу), *усякаму сваяку хоць бы па медзяку*
> (всякому свояку хотя б по медяку).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Ирония – это насмешка, а над чем? Что мало дали? А можно ли понять присказку как действие несправедливое - одну сестру надо бы в большей степени отметить, она этого заслужила.